# How can I delete LIB projects in a clean way?

Tags: sonarqube

Given two resource keys :

- A1 : `groupid:artifactid:trunk`
- A2 : `groupid:artifactid`

When I try to rename A1 to A2 through SonarQube's update key feature, I get a message stating that the key A1 can not be renamed because the key A2 "is the key of an existing resource".

After having had a look a the content of the database, it appears that A2 exists in the "projects" table as follows :

```
[1]
    0:  {
        id: "114499"
        k: "groupid:artifactid"
        nm: "groupid:artifactid"
        sc: "PRJ"
        qu: "LIB"
    }
```

I guess that the problem I'm facing is due to the way dependencies are handled by SonarQube : when analyzed, A1 is registered with the "branch" part in its name (and TRK qualifier), when another project is analyzed, his dependencies do not contain the branch information, thus a dependency to A2 is registered, not to A1. As SonarQube can't find A2 as a project (TRK qualifier) it creates A2 in its database as a new project with LIB qualifier. As a result, I can't rename A1 to A2 as A2 already exists.

I tried to delete A2 through the /api/projects webservice, but i get the following error which makes me think that the webservice is not able to handle LIB projects :

```
{
    err_code: 400
    err_msg: "Not valid project"
}
```

Question :

How can I delete in a clean way all unwanted "LIB" projects (i.e. removing all other rows in SonarQube database which may be using them) ?

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem today. I could not find the project anywhere so I ended up opening the database.

In the table 'projects' in your sonar database, all projects are listed. I searched for the project and updated the 'kee' column value to an used name. (A2 -> A21)

What I did is not actually a fix but it fixed the issue. I would not recommend doing this on a production system as I don't know what impact it may have on the data integrity.

Comment: Well that's my problem, the instance is running for 3 years (35 maven projects) now and I don't want to screw up the content of the DB. I hope that there is a cleaner way to do it.